# Using Left() with sort in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort columns name and date in ma table, I would like to sort first column name only by first 7 characters so suffix doesnt matter\

**example table:**

| name | xxx | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab12345cd | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:12 |
| ab12345c | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:11 |
| ab12345cd | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:10 |

table should look like this

| name | xxx | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab12345cd | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:10 |
| ab12345c | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:11 |
| ab12345cd | xxx | 1.1.20200 10:12 |

I have tried something like this:

`ws.Sort.Sortfields.Add Key:=Range(Left(A2,7) & CStr(lastline)), sorton:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlDescending`

How should my key range look like to sort only by first first 7 characters?
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Use a helper column with the 7 characters and sort by that (hide if necessary)?

Comment: Create a helper column with the left() result then sort by that column. You might copy.paste.special values and delete the column once finished.

Comment: @SJR Ok, we got this :)

Comment: @SolarMike - lol, great minds etc.

Answer (score 0):

### A Character-Limited Sort

- It will insert two entire columns adjacent to the left of the range and use them to sort the data.
- The first column will contain an ascending integer sequence (`1,2,3,...`*Rows.Count*), while the second column will contain the criteria columns data's first 7 characters.
- After the sort, the two entire columns will be deleted.
- Uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines to see how the addresses of the range and the criteria column have changed to finally become the same as they were at the start.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortCharLimited()
    
    Const sCol As Long = 1
    Const chCount As Long = 7
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(sCol)
    
    'Debug.Print rg.Address, crg.Address
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Insert two worksheet columns to the left of the range.
    rg.Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Insert xlShiftToLeft
    ' Combine the new columns into the range.
    Set rg = rg.Resize(, rg.Columns.Count + 2).Offset(, -2)
    
    'Debug.Print rg.Address, crg.Address
    
    ' In the first column write an ascending integer sequence.
    rg.Columns(1).Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & rg.Rows.Count & ")")
    ' In the second column write the first characters of the criteria column.
    rg.Columns(2).Value _
        = ws.Evaluate("LEFT(" & crg.Address & "," & chCount & ")")
    
    ' Sort, first by the sequence, then by the first characters.
    rg.Sort rg.Columns(1), xlDescending, , _
        rg.Columns(2), xlDescending, , , xlYes
    
    ' Delete the first two columns
    ' (the range's size is the same as the initial size).
    rg.Columns(1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Delete

    'Debug.Print rg.Address, crg.Address

End Sub
```